# The story of the rabbis in the haggada-mizva of afikoman

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

In the hagadah, did the rabbanim who stayed up all night get the miztva of afikoman?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you think they did not eat the *Afikoman*? There is a mitzvah to continue the discussion after *Nirtzah* if you can. They did so and went on the whole night!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where I learned this, but I learned that the "seder" in Bnei Barak was not on Passover, nor was it a seder - They were plotting the overthrow the Romans (they were discussing "yetziat Mitzrayim" *wink, wink*).  The morning shema bit was simply a way for the student to say, "Rabbotai, it's morning - you might be seen! Hide!"

Of course, this couldn't be written in the Talmud, which was written during Roman times, so it is written in metaphorical language.

Answer (score 0):

The Sfas Emes says it was not for sure on Pesach Night. Hence there was not for sure a need for Afikomon on that night.

Comment: Isn't the point of bringing this story to explain the statement in Avadim Hayinu, that "even if we were all wise etc."?

Comment: I might have thought the story could have happened as early as Rosh Chodesh...